# Создание неудаляемого виртуального рабочего стола (CreateDesktop)

Tags: visual-c++

Пишу консольную программку, проблема в том, что после создания виртуального рабочего стола функцией CreateDesktop, виртуальный рабочий стол удаляется (после закрытия программы). Как сделать так чтоб рабочий стол оставался в системе?

Comment: Пояснение: есть утилита sysinternals Desktops. Ее когда завершаешь через диспетчер задач, то рабочие столы остаются в системе. Как это сделано?

Comment: если приложение реализовано как служба то нужно ее остановить

Answer (score 1):

Все просто:  в CreateProcess есть структура STARTUPINFO а в ней параметр lpDesktop. Создаем процесс с нужным рабочим столом и он позже не удалится.